# Dualizing Sheaf Correspondence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a curve $C$. A morphism $f: C \to \mathbb{P}^1$ induces the dualizing sheaf $\omega_f$ endowed with  following characteristic property: $$ f_*(\omega_f) = \underline {Hom} _{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}}(f_*(\mathcal{O}_X), \omega_{\mathbb{P}^1})$$

where $\omega_{\mathbb{P}^1} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-2)$.

My question refers to my former question [Dualizing Sheaf unique determined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602251/dualizing-sheaf-unique-determined/2604627#2604627) concerning the uniqueness of the dualizing sheaf.

I want to know if there exist a bijective correspondence between

**quasicoherent $f_*(\mathcal{O}_C)$ modules $\mathcal{M}$**

and

**quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_C$ modules $\mathcal{F}$ with property: $\mathcal{M}= f_*(\mathcal{F})$**

If yes, does anybody have a good source/reference where this correspondence is introduced/explained. Futhermore does this correspondence has a name?

Comment: If $f$ is not an immersion, there is no hope for such a correspondence. Say we are over an algebraically closed field for simplicity and let $x,y\in C$ be two closed points lying above the same closed point $p=f(x)=f(y)$ and $x_*\mathcal{O}_x$, $y_*\mathcal{O}_y$ be the skyscraper sheaves at these points. Then $f_*x_*\mathcal{O}_x=f_*y_*\mathcal{O}_y=p_*\mathcal{O}_p$.

Comment: What is $C$? If it is $X$, then can you tell me why you expect this at all? Taking $X$ to be an elliptic curve, $f$ a degree 2 map to the projective line, calculate $f_*L$ for any non-trivial line bundle of degree zero.